# Reset Apple ID completely

Tags: icloud, apple-id, apple-store, game-center

Is it possible to reset the entire data present in your Apple ID.
From all the download apps to all the iCloud data and Game Center data too.
If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

One way I know is changing your e-mailaddress to another one and then sign up with your previous e-mailaddress. It will be a clean account at that time.

Comment: Thanks, let me try. Also, can you transfer game center's data to another apple id? If yes, how?

Comment: You cannot transfer data or purchases from one ID to another, no, but that's really a separate question.

Comment: @MixCoded Definitely have a look at [ask] before asking a second question. Each program stores data differently, so you would want to be pretty narrow about why you can't reset that game's state and/or what the goal is for the swap.

Comment: @MixCoded to transfer purchases, link the two together with family sharing. Note: you'll need the same credit card on both accounts.

Comment: @bmike Give him some credit, he's new (according to the reputation). ;)

Comment: @Rob Yes - also keep in mind, you don't see the deleted posts by a user. There may or may not be a pattern when moderators ask someone to read the guide or some specific actions that aren't out in the open. ;-) I 100% support being kind and giving lots of credit - we all start somewhere with no clothes, no reputation and no context.

Comment: @bmike up there you go